# Who killed Sauron?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, sauron, gollum

Is it correct to state that Frodo killed Sauron? Which is the role of Gollum/Smeagol? Frodo was the one in charge of destroying the Ring in the flames of Mount Doom (Amon Amarth of Mordor), but Gollum actually bit Frodo's finger and fell into the flames.

Comment: Nobody, he wasn't killed.

Comment: Nope. He was *diminished*

Comment: I'm sorry, what does it mean?

Comment: Don't think he's dead, he's a maia, but his spirit is so weak he cannot even cause as much harm as a light headache.

Comment: [Did Sauron survive?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12038/did-sauron-survive/12042#12042) - "*"If it [The One Ring] is destroyed, then he [Sauron] will fall; and his fall will be so low that none can foresee his arising ever again. For he will lose the best part of the strength that was native to him in his beginning, and all that was made or begun with that power will crumble, and he will be maimed for ever, becoming a mere spirit of malice that gnaws itself in the shadows, but cannot again grow or take shape.*" - The Return of the King

Comment: So it is correct to state that the diminishing of Sauron was caused by Eru Ilúvatar?

Comment: @lupod It's most correct, yes. That's arguably the moral of the *Lord of the Rings*: we incarnate creatures can struggle against Evil, but ultimately it can only be truly defeated by the Divine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Frodo did not kill Sauron**

Sauron did not die. It was said he put most of his power into the Ring, and thus when it perished, he was vanquished, but he did not actually die.

> He concentrated within the Ring a great part of his own fëa (soul). In this way, Sauron's fate became bound to that of the One Ring. If it were damaged or destroyed, so too would be Sauron's strength and power.
>   *- From the LOTR [wikia](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/One_Ring).*

Notice, nothing was ever said of him being *destroyed* or *killed*. I can't find the exact quote in the books yet, but there was a particular passage by one of the Wise Ones that said, if Sauron regains the Ring, he will have power to cover all the land in a second darkness, the ending of which cannot be forseen by anyone. But if the Ring is destroyed, he will lose most of his strength and power, and will diminish and his rising again can never be foreseen.

So no, it is not correct to say Frodo killed Sauron, because Sauron did not die. He was Maia before his corruption, and even at the end of the Third Age, he was still considered a being not of the lower order (the Elves, Men and Dwarves we see). He is still 'alive' as far as we know.

**Gollum, aka Smeagol helped (though unwillingly) to destroy the Ring, and was one of those to find it in the first place)**

It was Smeagol's friend, Deagol who fell into the river while the two were fishing at least 500 years before the events of The Fellowship of the Ring. He saw the Ring and retrieved it, and Smeagol, enamoured by the gold, strangled his friend to death and hid the body, taking the Ring for his own. After being kicked out of his home, he went to the Misty Mountains, where the Ring abandoned him just in time to meet Bilbo, who took it out. Smeagol (Gollum, by then) accused him of stealing the Ring, his Precious, as he called it.

After the Fellowship broke at Parth Galen, Frodo and Sam went through Emyn Muil, where they met him, Gollum having stalked the Fellowship since Moria. Partly out of fear of being beheaded by Sting (Frodo's sword), he agreed to help the hobbits to Mordor. Along the way, he betrayed them and turned up again in the end at Mount Doom. Frodo did not want to destroy the Ring at the very end, but Gollum attacked him and bit his finger (with the Ring) off. At that point, (in the books) Eru Illuvatar intervened and Gollum tripped of the ledge, taking the Ring down into the Cracks of Doom and getting it destroyed, along with himself. In the movie, Frodo fought him and he fell. Doesn't really matter. Point is, without him, the Ring would not have been destroyed in the end.

Comment: Why not? If it was divine intervention anyway then wouldn't Eru trip Frodo as well? Or make him sneeze so the ring would fall off?

Comment: I think Tolkien's idea was that Eru almost never intervened. If ur going by the book, he only stepped in right at the end veeery subtly after Frodo did almost everything humanly possible to get the ring destroyed, and there was nothing more anyone on Middle Earth could have done. Only then did he step in. If ur going by the movie, Frodo did trip and go off the edge, but he held on and Sam saved him. Gollum was so obsessed with the Ring, he didn't even care he was falling to his death.

Comment: Quote required has been provided by Valorum in comments section :)

Comment: @Neeshka Frodo was a reasonably good person still and had not yet been fully corrupted so maybe Eru didn't want to kill him. Golum had been utterly corrupted so Eru was being merciful killing him.

Comment: @bellerophon &ASH so you guys say even though Frodo (and many others) would have died anyways as Sauron already dispatched his servants to collect the ring Eru wouldn't push anyone else if Gollum wasn't conveniently available?

Comment: @Neeksha No, I am saying Eru would rather kill Gollum than Frodo so he waited till Gollum had taken the Ring before tripping them into the fire.

Comment: @Neeshka, no I'm saying that Eru would not have intervened unless there was no other option. When Frodo claimed the Ring, there still were options: either Sam or Gollum could have still gotten the Ring into the Fire. But when Gollum had the Ring, noone else could have done anything anymore, so Eru did.